# Change Foreign AudioSessions AudioEndpoints in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, audio, naudio

So I've been researching for quite a while now, how to specifically change the AudioEndpoint of an AudioSession, or implement routing for AudioStreams not native to my App and all the answers I got are either:

1. From Back When XP was the hot new thing and basically say, Microsoft doesn't allow external access to that kind of stuff, which doesn't really make any sense anymore since a ton of apps can change your Default Audio Settings.

or

2. Pointing to NAudio or the Docs which appear to be down. So does offer NAudio the capability to rout other AudioSessions to other Endpoints, and if not is there any way at all, since considering the Win11 Volume Mixer it is definetly possible for Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement the stream routing feature. Stream routing is the ability of a media application to switch streams between devices with minimal interruption to the playback or the capture session.

You could use `Core Audio APIs` implement the stream routing feature by handling stream switching from an existing device to a new default audio endpoint.

To implement the stream routing feature, a client must listen for two types of events: device change notifications and session disconnect notifications.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Relevant Notifications for Stream Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/relevant-device-notifications-for-stream-routing)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful in understanding, the general gist of specific Stream management. Which is awesome as I am quiet a Newbie with, WASAPI and the WinAPI in general. But, and I may have worded my question a bit wrong. How can I either obtain control and restart the Audio Streams of a Foreign, Audio Session. Or implement routing in a way similar to the Win11 Volume Mixer. And since AudioSessions already provide a fair bit amount of control I.E MuteState and Volume Level I thought I could work with them. But well tl;dr I also want to AudioEndpoints of Foreign AudioSessions.

Comment: You could refer to the thread: https://superuser.com/questions/258969/routing-applications-sound-to-different-sound-device-windows